# How do i convert the tree's nodes to nodes of the queue?

Tags: algorithm, queue, copy-constructor, breadth-first-search

i'm using a queue to implement breadth first search. The nodes of the tree are of type **state**, while those in the queue are of type **node**.

```
    struct node
{ 
 int b1,b2,b3,b4;
 node* link;
}
```

---

```
struct state
{
 int b1,b2,b3,b4;
 state* rightChild;
 state* leftChild;
};
```

The Queue.enqueue() function's prototype is:

```
     bool enqueue(node n);
```

to pass to it the tree's nodes (of type state) , i have to either convert them by a copy constructor or an overloaded assignment operator, OR- i can make **Queue** the base class of **state** so that the state objects are accepted in the queue by polymorphism. 
      Now what's a good way of doing this?

Comment: Err, don't you need to be keeping a queue of `state *`s for this to possibly work?

Comment: @ veredesmarald   but `state` doesn't have a state *link member necessary in the queue

Comment: If you plan on using this queue for BFS, you need to be able to find the neighbours (in the original tree) of each node you dequeue and add them to the end of the queue. If your queue is just storing the data from the tree node (`b1 ... b4`) rather than a pointer to the actual tree node, how will you accomplish this?

Comment: @ veredesmarald that occurred to me- so one way of accomplishing that would be to make state the base class of queue, wouldn't it? But then how would i be able to pass `state` nodes to the queue (since polymorphism works the other way around) ?

Comment: Are you writing C++? If so the usual approach to a container like a queue would be to use a template, so the queue nodes can store whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
struct node 
{
    struct state* treeNode;
    struct node* link;  
};
```

your queue can now simply store node* pointers